# I have some difficulties when I try to update to angular2 release candidate

Tags: angular

[image: This are the errors that I receive]

> My system js config looks like

```
/**
 * Created by nick_ on 5/7/2016.
 */
(function(global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'moment':                     'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        paths: {
            underscore: './node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
        }
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

> I don't understand why he tries to load the angular library from
>   /angular2/core and not from /node_modules/@angular/comon ?
>   Can anyone explain how systemJs loads the files ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the import to

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core'
```

Comment: I changed all imports to be from @angular instead of angular2

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was because I use ng-2 bootstrap and that one is not updated to angular2 if anyone want to update ng-2 bootstrap to angular 2 relese version just replace all the imports from min.js replace angular2 with @angular, and for the angular2/animation_builder requires replace with @angular/platform_browser